# Beyond Compare 4 and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I have configured Beyond Compare 4 as an external tool. And now I see bizarre behavior. It works as expected for the first compare (first tab of the Beyond Compare). But when I'm opening a send tab (starting to compare a send file without closing Beyond Compare instance) it does not work. The followed actions are happening:

1. VS creates a temporary file in %temp%\TFSTemp
2. New tab of Beyond Compare will be created
3. The temporary file will be removed(! why? !)
4. Beyond Compare can't compare files and Beyond Compare shows an error:

> "Cannot open file
> 'c:\users.....\Temp\TFSTemp\vctmp49504_39879.csproj'. The system
> cannot find file specified"

The followed settings

[image]

does not solve the problem.

Is it a known bug? Is there any workaround? This behavior makes actually Beyond Compare unusable :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you call **bcomp.exe** for diffs and merges.

This opens every compare and merge in a separate helper process, allowing version control to detect when the comparison is complete.

If you use **bcompare.exe**, it opens all comparisons in a single process, so version control can't detect when the comparison is complete if you launch more than one diff.

For more info: [Using Beyond Compare with Version Control Systems - Visual Studio - Team Foundation Server (TFS)](https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#visualstudio-tfs)

Comment: Thank you! I was so blind! I've missed bcomp.exe as it has a standard windows application icon and not an icon of Beyond Compare. It was quite stupid from my side :)